# How to Set the Default View Location (Cesium 1.6)

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I want to set the default view/home location for a cesium app.

I don't just want to flyTo the location once; I want the location set as the default/home - so that it can be used elsewhere in the app - e.g. in the [HomeButton](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/HomeButton.html) Widget.

I've tried setting the `Camera.DEFAULT_VIEW_RECTANGLE` [(docs here)](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Camera.html) like this:

```
var extent = Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(117.940573,-29.808406,118.313421,-29.468825);

viewer.camera.DEFAULT_VIEW_RECTANGLE = extent;
```

But it doesn't work..

For completeness, here's how I'm initializing the app:

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
        terrainProvider : new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
            url : '//cesiumjs.org/stk-terrain/tilesets/world/tiles'
        }),
        mapProjection : new Cesium.WebMercatorProjection(),
        timeline: false,
        animation: false,
});
```

Any suggestions?
If any further info is needed please let me know.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`DEFAULT_VIEW_RECTANGLE` is a static property on `Cesium.Camera`.  This way, you can assign the value before `Viewer` is constructed, and then newly constructed widgets will initialize to your custom default view rectangle.

*EDIT:* Also, be aware of [`Camera.DEFAULT_VIEW_FACTOR`](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Camera.html#DEFAULT_VIEW_FACTOR).  You can set this to zero, to make the default view match your rectangle exactly.  Its default value will make your default view stand well back from your chosen rectangle.

```
var extent = Cesium.Rectangle.fromDegrees(117.940573,-29.808406,118.313421,-29.468825);

Cesium.Camera.DEFAULT_VIEW_RECTANGLE = extent;
Cesium.Camera.DEFAULT_VIEW_FACTOR = 0;

var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    terrainProvider : new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
        url : '//cesiumjs.org/stk-terrain/tilesets/world/tiles'
    }),
    mapProjection : new Cesium.WebMercatorProjection(),
    timeline: false,
    animation: false,
    baseLayerPicker: false
});
```

Answer (score 3):

overwrite home button event, like this:

```js
 viewer.homeButton.viewModel.command.beforeExecute.addEventListener(
   function(e) {
      e.cancel = true;
      viewer.scene.camera.flyTo(homeCameraView);
   });
```